# Ubuntu Studio 12.04 won't boot 

Tags: boot-failure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu 12.04 boot only when USB drive is connected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144678/ubuntu-12-04-boot-only-when-usb-drive-is-connected)

I'll warn ye first off I'm still relatively new to Ubuntu and Linux.

I installed Ubuntu Studio on a spare hard-drive (formatted beforehand etc.). Install works fine (off live USB) but after the restart it gets as far as an unresponsive black screen with a white cursor flashing in the top left.

(Does this mean Grub cannot load a kernal? If so how do I fix?)

When I boot of the live USB again it is as if I booted of the hard-drive, i.e. I need my profile password to access and the system and don't have to mount the filesystem.

I have Vista dual booting with the normal Ubuntu on another hard-drive and I get this black screen w/flashing cursor for a second just before I get to the Grub screen that allows me to choose the OS to use.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot with the USB, opened a terminal window and run

`sudo grub-install /dev/sda && sudo update-grub`

It seems that Ubuntu Studio has a bug that installs GRUB onto the USB key and not the hard drive. The command installs GRUB on the MBR of the hard disk, making it bootable.

Apologies for the duplicate of [Ubuntu 12.04 boot only when USB drive is connected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144678/ubuntu-12-04-boot-only-when-usb-drive-is-connected?rq=1), only found it after.

Comment: @kamil cheers for adding the apostrophe in the title and not bothering to try answer my question. Helped a lot.

Comment: you might want to accept your answer if that help solved your boot problem, that way this post will be marked as solved. Thank you.